# Solution for loading hint from Database

Tags: sql-server, web-services

I'm using `selectbox` for your to choose multiple username. The username are retrieved from database and i use `select username from users`. Data are loaded all when the page rendered.
For now it worked because doesn't have many users, I assume that the table has 1 millions records then loading all of the table will take plenty of time. If i send `request for query` when user starts typing, it will not fast enough to retrieve data.
So how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to ensure a minimum of 3-4 characters are supplied to the backend query (delay the query until 3-4 chars are entered), then perform a 'starts with' lookup on an INDEXED column in your database.

This should restrict the data searched/returned. Ensure the query is indexed!

Comment: what do you mean 'the query is indexed', how to index a query. And when keep send request to server when user type more than minimum of characters, may it will have some delay?. Any way to boots the server (storage ways, cache or something else)

Answer (score 0):

Use pagination technique. Run the query to retrieve 100 records. Then if still scrolling, can retrieve more. Must be possible.

Comment: i think user won't scroll in `select tag`

Comment: In select how will he show million of records then?

Comment: i mean user will type, and i have to show the hint to select, i use select2 https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple